# Debug > Start New Instance compared to Start Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Aside from using the startup project, are there any differences the Start Debugging, and right clicking on a project, and selecting Debug > Start New Instance button?

It seems like sometimes Start New Instance will take the last successful build if there were no changes. It may also build the selected project, while Start Debugging will compile the whole solution.

Visual Studio (2017 if version specific)

Answer (score 3):

Both will launch the project in debug mode with some differences.

1. With **Debug > Start New Instance**, you can launch as many instances as you want.
2. **Start Debugging (F5 shortcut)** will launch the Startup projects while with **Debug > Start New Instance** will launch the project that was selected.